# C# JSON data serialized and binded to DataGridView

Tags: json, datagridview, xml-serialization, bind

I have this data class for storing data parsed from JSON formatted web data (using `Json.NET` library):

```
[Serializable()]
public class MovieData
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string OrigName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "genres")]
    public string[] Genres { get; set; }
}
```

The next class is for to be able serialize collection of `MovieData` objects:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("MovieCollection")]
public class MovieCollection
{
    [XmlArray("Movies")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Movie", typeof(Movie))]
    public List<Movie> movies = new List<MovieData>();
}
```

Finally, I need to bind such a collection of `MovieData` to `DataGridView` (or single `MovieData` object to `DataGridViewRow`), like:

```
dgvMovies.DataSource = movieCollection.movies;
```

Is it possible to bind it without hard-setting of `DataGridViewColumn` collection before? Native data types are not problem, problem is `string[] Genres` array, which I need to format it in `DataGridView` in some way, like:

```
"genres[0] / genres[0] / ... genres[n]"
```

At this moment, while simply setting `DataSource` to collectin, this array is ignored (is not displayed anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MovieData` class, you can add the following property :

```
public string GenresAsString 
{ 
    get { return String.Join("/", Genres); }
    set { Genres = value.Split('/'); } 
}
```

You will surely have to improve the setter to make it more resilient (triming, removing empty genres) if you plan to let the user modify this value. 
Else you can remove the setter.